# Why are the elements removed on booth Lists?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why does it remove the list element from booth lists?
Is it in Darts just a pointer?
How to fix it?

```
class _ResultsState extends State<Results> {
    var _league;
    var originalLeague;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _league = API_Manager.getLeagueFull(widget.leagueId, widget.seasonId, context);
    }

    void filterData(String teamName) async {
        if (originalLeague == null) {
          _league = await _league;
          originalLeague = List.from(_league);
        }
        List<LeagueModel> leagues = List.from(originalLeague);

        print('List length: ${originalLeague[0].dates.length}');

        if (teamName != 'Kein Filter') {
          leagues[0].dates.removeWhere((element) => !element.guestTeam.contains(teamName) && !element.homeTeam.contains(teamName));
        }

        print('List length now: ${originalLeague[0].dates.length}');
        print('New List length: ${leagues[0].dates.length}');

        setState(() {
          _league = filteredList(leagues);
        });
    }

    Future<List<LeagueModel>> filteredList( List<LeagueModel> list) async {
        return list;
    }
 }
```

Console Output:

```
flutter: List length: 30
flutter: List length now: 10
flutter: New List length: 10
```

Edit:
As recommendet i testet [...data] and List.from(data) but it still removes the elements from booth lists. Updated the code above

Comment: u can use data.toList() to clone the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It about instance, try `newList = [...oldList]` or `newList = List.from(oldList)`.

**Example**:
[image]

Comment: Seems not to work, i updated my code in the question and the output.

Comment: does `dates` is `List` too?

Comment: i think that makes no sense...if i clone the main list and change something in the clone, the original list shouldnt be changed. i think its more a thing of the state in flutter.

Comment: Remember you want **a filter**, not **chance the original data**, or... I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Tobias look at my answer, ilve updated it example againt with your details, if it not help, ill remove my answer.